# How to write Laravel eloquent query where (condition) and (condition2 or condition 3)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Lets say we have SQL like this

```
select * from cards
where (deck_id=${deck_id})
and (added_by =${user_id} or is_available = 1)
```

And want to write in Laravel eloquent

I tried using the following queries but the result is not same as it suppose to be.

```
Card::where(['deck_id'=>$deck_id,'added_by'=>$user_id])
    ->orWhere(['deck_id'=>$deck_id,'is_available'=>1])
    ->get();
```

---

```
Card::where(['deck_id'=>$deck_id])
        ->Where(['added_by'=>$user_id])
        ->orWhere('is_available',1)
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this :

```
Card::where('deck_id', $deck_id)
   ->where(function ($query) use($user_id){
         $query->where('added_by', $user_id)
         ->orWhere('is_available', 1);
    })
   ->get();
```